# Solana Pay Point of Sale - How to Display Public Key of Sender on Recent Transactions Page

Tags: transactions, solana-pay

Just forked the [point of sale repo](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/tree/master/point-of-sale), and I'm trying to figure out how to isolate the sender's public key and display it on the Recent Transactions page via the `Transactions.tsx` file.

Ideally, I'd like to see the sender's public key rather than the transaction signature as shown below. This is the default:
[image]

Assuming I have to initialize this somewhere (likely when the transaction is created), but I'm very new to this and I'm a bit lost.

Appreciate any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the TransactionsProvider you would need to make the necessary changes to retrieve the source public key and then add it to the state with the transaction.

[Here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/b8da65e012e243bcbc013995941be4cbce633a59/point-of-sale/src/client/components/contexts/TransactionsProvider.tsx#L130) is where the instruction is parsed from the transaction. A few lines below that, you can see the variable ‘info’ being set, ‘info.source’ is the value that you are looking for.

[Here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-pay/blob/b8da65e012e243bcbc013995941be4cbce633a59/point-of-sale/src/client/components/contexts/TransactionsProvider.tsx#L145) is a place you see it being used to check for self transfers.